# flask bokeh server- figure does not render (ubuntu) but works on local machine

Tags: python, flask, bokeh, web-development-server

I've created a bokeh plot that is accessible through Flask. I am able to successfully run bokeh server through flask on my local machine via

bokeh server `bokeh serve--allow-websocket-origin=localhost:5000 filename.py`

flask `python run.py` on two command windows

Now I want to do the same thing but on a virtual machine running ubuntu. Using the exact same commands on two putty windows no longer work. I am able to access non-bokeh html pages though.

When trying to access the bokeh plot, I get:

> OSError: Cannot pull session document because we failed to connect to the server (to start the server, try the 'bokeh serve' command)

but I already intitiated `bokeh serve`

this is the code snippet in flask that will call bokeh server

```
@main.route("/grid")
def bokehserver():
    session=pull_session(url="http://localhost:5006/filename")
    bokeh_script=autoload_server(None, url="http://localhost:5006/filename",session_id=session.id)
    return render_template("bokserv.html",bokeh_script=bokeh_script)
```

edit: I'm reading something about 'linux server configuration files' for running bokeh server on linux. I have not made such configuration files. Can someone confirm whether these are totally necessary? I don't want to overstuff my project with excess. In many examples I've seen, the developer uses nginx and gunicorn and other things to get flask/bokeh up and running, but so far I've been able to avoid these extra layers..

edit2: `bokeh serve --show filename.py` in the ubuntu terminal generates the standard messages as if it is working but it doesn't open the browser to display the figure.

Comment: It looks to me like you're running on "localhost:5000" on your VM so your Windows PC (host) can't connect. You should try running on 0.0.0.0:5000 on your VM and see if that fixes it.

Comment: sadly it yields the same result, I can access the flask website, but no bokeh server plot renders

Comment: I don't have a bokeh plot even locally. What should I do?? I'm going crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the configuration files referenced in the initial post and used `bokeh serve --allow-websocket-origin=(my ip):5000 filename.py`.

Then in the flask file `from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix`

then outside of the `app.route(/)` i put `app.wsgi_app=ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)`

then I navigated to `(my ip):5000`

and it worked.